# How to extract clear cut areas from dried trees in forests

Tags: imagery, ndvi, aerial-photography

I have 40 cm resolution aerial image with visible and near-infrared bands. Purpose is to extract dried trees in forest. I used multiresolution segmentation algorithm to extract individual trees and used NDVI to classify dried and healthy trees, but there are clear cut areas in the study area, and they give the same NDVI value as dried trees. I even checked RGB and NIR values of segments and they also give the same value as dried trees. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not too sure, if this is the right way to go, but you could search on alternative vegetation indices like [SAVI](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220040775_Huete_A_R_A_soil-adjusted_vegetation_index_SAVI_Remote_Sensing_of_Environment): "The soil-adjusted vegetation index was developed as a modification of the Normalized Difference Vegetation Index to correct for the influence of soil brightness when vegetative cover is low." ([src](http://wiki.landscapetoolbox.org/doku.php/remote_sensing_methods:soil-adjusted_vegetation_index))

Comment: @tareq, thanks for your advice, I tried SAVI, but met the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have any associated elevation data like LIDAR? I would have imagined clear-cut areas would return a different height in first return? You could then distinguish between areas that are returning similar NDVI values for dried trees by their elevation.

Comment: @Hornbydd, thanks, it is good advice, but I haven't got any elevation data for this image.

Comment: I think that you are too down-in-the-weeds in trying to identify individual crowns. I would delineate a characteristic of the feature class that you are after (presence, percent cover, etc...) and pull the associated spectral signatures across all bands, don't throw away data, including any transformations and then pass the data to a formalized model. In just using NDVI you are collapsing the variation into univariate data and loosing considerable power in discrimination across the multivariate data. This is why there is class confusion.

Comment: How did you "check" the spectra? Did you perform a separability analysis? I have performed this type of modeling on numerous occasions and there has always been separability in standing dead and down woody debris. I would follow @Tom Dilts advice and utilize the texture (focal variance) of the red and NIR bands. You could also explore other segmentation algorithms that use texture as a variance reduction criteria.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans. thanks for your comments. I checked spectral variability just visually from image object information of objects. But I haven't done separability analysis, could you please provide some references to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't differentiate them spectrally then it has to be based on some other criteria.  You state that you are using a "multiresolution segmentation algorithm" which suggests that you might have access to software that can do object-oriented classification.  You might want to consider textural, shape, or spatial characteristics that differentiate individual dead tree crowns from clear cuts.  Size and crown shape are two differences that come to my mind.

Comment: thank you for your advices. Yes have access to eGognition software, and created multiresolution segmentation with this software which takes into account, shape and texture, but clear cuts are not so big areas, their size is quite similar to trees, it is difficult to differentiate them with dead trees.

Comment: I tried different texture information of objects but couldn't see the variation

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the spectral data you would need another way to differentiate the two.  I know point cloud data from LiDAR surveys would allow you to do this, but you might not have it available or in the same time frame as your photos.  It's a vague hint, but looking for elevation datasets that show a difference between the bare earth DSM and some of the point returns might be your best bet.

Comment: Thank you, but I have no any DSM data for this analysis.